# Why is my IBOutlet unrecognized in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, iboutlet

During my project I wanted to connect a text field to my code, so I used an `IBOutlet` which is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV109.png

So I get an error in which it says expected declaration. 
I using Xcode 9 beta 3 although I used to get that error in Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: You can't write code that needs evalutation at the root of the controller. You need to put it in a method/function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code setting the textField's text into viewDidLoad() or another function.

Comment: but now i get "Only instance properties can be declared @IBOutlet"

Comment: It sounds like you moved both the IBOutlet declaration line and the line to set the textfield into viewDidLoad. If that's the case, you only needed to move the line editing the properties of the IBOutlet into viewDidLoad and leave the actual IBOutlet variable at the root level inside your class.

Comment: simplify please because  i am a newbie thanks for the help !